# Tracking pppoe interfaces

Tags: linux-networking, ifconfig, point-to-point-protocol, pppoe

I have a set of PPP interfaces on my Linux server. But on bouncing(ifdown; ifup)  the interfaces which are not working, the PPP interfaces takes the lowest possible interface number.

If I have a PPP interface configured as ppp12, it will take a name like ppp5 if the ppp5 interface number  is available at the point. Is there a way to track which is the exact interface name corresponding to it's configuration(/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ppp3)?

Comment: Did you try to put `DEVICE="ppp3"` in your `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ppp3` file ?

Comment: @Yura Vasylenko I already have DEVICE="pppX" in the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same problem at my Debian Wheezy and resoved in this way:

1) at file(for example) /etc/ppp/peers/pppDOMRU i've added new parameter **ipparam pppDOMRU**, and config begal look like

```
 hide-password
 lcp-echo-interval 20
 lcp-echo-failure 3
 connect /bin/true
 noauth
 noaccomp
 default-asyncmap
 plugin rp-pppoe.so eth1
 noipdefault
 nopersist
 maxfail 1
 user "some username"
 ipparam pppDOMRU
```

2) Then I modified /etc/ppp/ip-up. You can find modified script [here](http://pastebin.com/8rSUv4dt)

When interface is bringing up, this modified script renames interface according **ipparam** parameter like this:

```
pppDOMRU  Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  P-t-P:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
          RX packets:2754927 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2644464 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:1114129844 (1.0 GiB)  TX bytes:296204844 (282.4 MiB)
```